# IP address of WSFC

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

Kindly asking you to help me to figure out how can I find virtual IP address of my Windows Server Failover Cluster. Search on the net doesn`t give any useful information. I need this IP in order to be to create cluster and enable Always On for my SQL Server 2016. Thank you

Comment: You don't need to know the cluster management ip in order to enable AlwaysOn. You'll need the individual nodes names which can be returned from `get-clusternode` in powershell given you know the cluster name.

Answer (score 1):

In FailOverClusterManager, click cluster and find its properties.

This video shows how: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=so_l_OpF1n4

It is left part of application where is the cluster list and the properties is on right side, when you click the cluster.

This is how you find the manager:

> Server roles and features are managed by using Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-ins. To open the failover cluster snap-in, click Start, click Administrative Tools, and then click Failover Cluster Manager.

(more info: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770737(v=ws.11).aspx)